# How to remove/disable comments which generated by ProGuard

Tags: android, comments, proguard, deobfuscation

I need help about disabling comment generated by ProGuard in obfuscating a project. because somehow these comments reveal the true source code.

SO, is there any command/script which we can add to "proguard-project.txt" and prevents these comments.

Comments like this:

// Referenced classes of package com.myTopG.steel:

//            TEE_Result, TEE_DROID, z

thanks..

Answer (score 2):

Compiled bytecode doesn't contain any Java comments, so there is nothing for ProGuard to remove. The comments that your quote are probably generated by your decompiler.

Comment: Using Eclipse Build 22.3.0 any clue how to remove automatically these generated comments? I'm really appreciate it.